# "Float on top" in all windows

Tags: google-chrome, window-manager

Specific apps have an option under `Window`->`Float on Top` which allows this kind of behavior:

[image]

The problem is that I'd like to achieve this on all windows. Specifically I'd like to choose specific windows say of Chrome and do this. I'd like a video-player floating on top (and always staying on top even as I switch to other apps). But I'd like other windows in Chrome (say my email) to also be on top. I cannot seem to achieve this anywhere and it's a bit frustrating to not have this simple customization.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

**EDIT** to be more specific I'm looking to be able to pick and choose any window from any app and make it float. This is already achievable by the Notes and Stickies native apps so this functionality exists within the OS. You can just open both apps and select Window->Float on Top. They will keep floating above other apps. I'd just like for this functionality to be available across all apps.

Comment: You may need to clarify the specifics of what you're after. After all, saying *"I'd like to achieve this on all windows"* is sort of, well, impossible once you have too many windows open. Is it just that you want to be able to pick and choose any window from any app and make it float if and when you want?

Comment: If you simply want to do this in chrome, there are quite a few extensions. Especially if it's a video player you want to do that with: [Picture in Picture for every website](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/picture-in-picture-for-ev/hepbieccgbieoeaigepkojmogpkjfpin?hl=fi) ...and there are probably many more, if you search for "floating video" or "picture in picture" in the chrome webstore. — [Flobro (chrome app)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/flobro-floating-browser-w/faaljkdndnfoagcmhedlmbgieoocemch): for any website you want to float on top.

Comment: @Monomeeth indeed. I'm looking for exactly what you said: "want to be able to pick and choose any window from any app and make it float if and when you want". This is already achievable by the Notes and Sticky native apps so this functionality exists within the OS. Just open both apps and select Window->Float on Top. They will keep floating above other apps. I'd just like for this functionality to be available across *all* apps... if possible.

Comment: @Joonas this is not the same I'm afraid. 1) it only works with video and 2) only works 1 window at a time (not multiple windows). I'd be happy if this was available only for Chrome tabs though... but isn't so far (even Flobro allows only 1 window).

Comment: Since nobody has stepped up, I'll say that there used to be something called "afloat", which allowed you to do keep windows in front. I thought it had been dead since long ago, but it seems there's some hope. This seems like your best bet if you want to take the leap: https://github.com/rwu823/afloat/issues/54#issuecomment-484368798 Pay attention to at least all the following posts after that one. — If this doesn't do it for you, I'm certain there's nothing else out there that can do this, unless you downgrade your OS version.